# Subset of a unit interval generated by a non-principal ultrafilter is non-measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, solution-verification, filters

I was reading about use of ultrafilters in general topology and found a [document](https://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Edrorbn/classes/9293/131/ultra.pdf) by Dror Bar-Natan.  It contained this problem, so I embarked on solving it. In my opinion, it's rather interesting.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a non--principle ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$. Define $A = \left\{ \sum_{n \in F} 2^{-n} | F \in \mathcal{F}  \right\}$. Here $\lambda$ denotes Lebesgue measure on [0,1].

> The problem is to identify if $A$ is Lebesgue measurable.

My attempt:

(1)As $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter it must be true that $\forall F,G \in \mathcal{F} \; . \; F \cap G \neq 0$, so it must be the case that $\forall x \in A \; . \; 1 - x \in A^\complement$, at least, then $x$ is not dyadic . Also, as ultrafilters are maximal,actually , $A^\complement = (1 - A) \setminus Z_2$, where $Z_2$ is countable set of dyadic non-zero numbers in $[0,1]$. The function $1-x$ preserves Lebesgue measure and $\lambda(Z_2) = 0$, so, if $A$ were measurable, then $\lambda(A) = \lambda(A^\complement)$. As

$$ 1 = \lambda[0,1] = \lambda(A \cup A^\complement) = \lambda(A) + \lambda(A^\complement) =2\lambda(A), $$

it follows, that  $\lambda(A) = 1/2$ . From now on, assume that $A$ is measurable.

(2) being non-principal means for $\mathcal{F}$ that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} . \exists F \in \mathcal{F} : n \not \in F$. This implies that both $A$ and $A^\complement$ are everywhere dense in $[0,1]$. Moreover, if two numbers are different in a finite number of digits in their binary expansion, they must be either in $A$ or $A^\complement$ together. Whence, repeated reasoning from (1) with function $b + a - x $ shows that for any dyadic half-intervals $(a,b]$  ( or $[a,b),[a,b],(a,b)$ ) we have $\lambda(A \cap (a,b]) = \lambda(A^\complement \cap (a,b]) = \frac{1}{2}\lambda (a,b]$.

(3) Define auxiliary measures $\mu$ and $\mu'$ by $\mu(X) = \lambda(A \cap X)$ and $\mu'(X) = \lambda(A^\complement \cap X)$. Note, that dyadic intervals as above generate Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$ . So by (2) $\mu = \mu' = \frac{1}{2} \lambda$ . However, by construction $\mu(A) = 1/2$ and $\mu'(A) = 0$, a contradiction! Thus, $A$ is not measurable$\square$

---

If I'm wrong here you are welcome to bash me.

If my result is correct, then it must be impossible to construct such non-principal ultrafilters without some weaker form of choice, as existence of non-measurable sets is equivalent to it.

Comment: Your last paragraph might not be quite right, depending on what you mean by it. The statement "Every filter can be extended to an ultrafilter" (the Boolean prime ideal theorem) is known to be strictly weaker than the axiom of choice.  Any ultrafilter extending the filter of cofinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is a non-principle ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$, and so such an ultrafilter can exist even when the axiom of choice is false.  That being said, people usually think of the Boolean prime ideal theorem as a weaker version of AC.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Thank you for your input. I stated the result as I recalled it, and it is actually is a weaker version of the axiom of choice. Probably, because I remembered 
 something like 'in constructive mathematics all sets are measurable'.